# Append html to all lines not ending with html tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to append `<br/>` to all lines that do not end with an html tag, but I'm unable to get it working.

I've got this so far, but it seems to match nothing at all (in PHP).

```
$message=preg_replace("/^(.*[^>])([\n\r])$/","\${1}<br/>\${2}",$message);
```

Any ideas on how to get this working properly?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you're looking for this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: are you sure you don't want nl2br() ??

Comment: To allow my users to input line feeds without having to type <br/> each time over and over in order to have a newline. I know there are better alternatives, but I need to keep old input decent as well.

Comment: nl2br adds a br on each line, I only need one on lines not ending with `>`

Comment: It's not clear where this text is coming from. I'm assuming a `<textarea>`, in which case your newlines are delimited by `\n` and not `\r\n`. This might be the problem wherever the text is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `m` modifier on your regex:

```
$message=preg_replace("/^(.*[^>])$/m", "$1<br/>\n", $message);
//                                 ^
//                                Here
```

`m` makes `^` and `$` match start/end of lines in addition to start/end of string.
No `[\n\r]` needed.
Also, why do you want to match all the line to just put it back after ?

It is actually as simple as

```
$message = preg_replace ('/([^>])$/m', '$1<br />', $message);
```

Example code:

```
<?php
  $message = "<strong>Hey</strong>
  you,
  No you don't have to go !";
  $output = preg_replace ('/([^>])$/m', '$1<br />', $message);
  echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($output) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track. I can't really explain why, but your suggestion also added a `<br/>` on a new line following one that ends with `>`. Here's what worked for me `$message = preg_replace ('#([^>])(\r\n|\r|\n)$#mi', '$1<br/>$2', $message);`

Comment: Can you put your example text that failed with my answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$message = preg_replace('~(?<![\h>])\h*\R~', '<br/>', $message);
```

where:

```
`\h` is for horizontal white spaces (space and tab)
`\R` is for newline
(?<!..) is a negative lookbehind (not preceded by ..)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this that works somehow, see http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/259-vvp:

```
<?php
//
$message0 = "You are OK.
<p>You are good,</p>
You are the universe.
<strong>Go to school</strong>
This is the end.
";

//
if(preg_match("/^WIN/i", PHP_OS))
{
  $message = preg_replace('#(?<!\w>)[\r]$#m', '<br />', $message0);
}
else
{
  $message = preg_replace('#(?<!\w>)$#m', '<br />', $message0);
}

echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 90px;\">";
echo($message);
echo "</textarea>";

//
?>
```

Gives:

```
You are OK.<br />
<p>You are good,</p>
You are the universe.<br />
<strong>Go to school</strong>
This is the end.<br /><br />
```

Add a < br /> if not ended up with a HTML tag like:
< /p>, < /strong>, ...

Explanation:

```
(?<!\w>): negative lookbehind, if a newline character is not preceded
   by a partial html close tag, \w word character + closing >, like a>, 1> for h1>, ...
[\r\n]*$: end by any newline character or not.
m: modifier for multiline mode.
```